# How did the allies address the economic debts of axis nations following world war 2?

Tags: world-war-two, economy

How were the economic debts of axis nations addressed after World War 2? I am particularly interested in:

- Plans that were agreed upon to address debt and reconstruction of Germany and Japan.
- How were the plans implemented? What worked? What did not work?
- How were banks and financial organizations that had outstanding loans to Germany and Japan addressed?
- How were the finances tracked? Were there ledgers? What branch or department of The United States government was responsible for the book-keeping? Are these records available today?
- How did the Marshall Plan affect outstanding debts of axis nations and plans in progress?
- What conditions had to be met before a line item of debt was considered closed? For example, did denazification play a role?
- How much debt was eventually written off?
- How were the assets from Jewish citizens of Germany treated after the war? Did the allies ever attempt a program to restore homes and property to their rightful owners?

One of the things I am interested in is how plans were overtaken by events. What were the largest and most expensive misconceptions in the initial plans. I would be interested in plans drawn up before the end of the war through the execution of the Marshall plan. What legacies are still outstanding today? Plans and estimates are often treated as if they are set in stone. People who treat plans and estimates as gospel are often disappointed. There is great value in understanding the causes of the differences between actual and planned actions.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: I do agree. If I can find some references, I will certainly add them.

Comment: Might start with [Marshall Plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshall_Plan) or [Economic Aftermath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aftermath_of_World_War_II#Economic_aftermath)

Comment: Well, [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II_reparations) might be a start then. What do you want to know that isn't answered there?

Comment: Most helpful - I will go through this and post an update if needed.

Comment: Any plan before the end of the war was rapidly overcome by events, so what time period are you most interested in?

Comment: German debts are mostly covered in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Agreement_on_German_External_Debts

Comment: Hi Jon - exactly. One of the things I am interested in is how plans were overtaken by events. What were the largest and most expensive misconceptions in the initial plans. I would be interested in plans drawn up before the end of the war through the execution of the Marshall plan. What legacies are still outstanding today? Plans and estimates are often treated as if they are set in stone. People who treat plans and estimates as gospel are often disappointed. There is great value in understanding the causes of the differences between actual and planned actions.